# How can I use 'ReplayKit2 - Broadcast Upload Extension' on flutter plugin

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter, flutter-plugin

Just like the title, I write a plugin for flutter.

On iOS, if I want to use ReplayKit Broadcast Upload Extension, I must new a target.
How can I integrated it into plugin?

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://pub.dev/packages/replay_kit_launcher